# Arquillian doesn't recognize shared libraries in Weblogic 12c

Tags: jakarta-ee, shared-libraries, weblogic, weblogic12c, jboss-arquillian

I'm using Arquillian to run an integration test in Weblogic 12c and it does't recognize shared libraries deployed in container.

The EAR is implanted correctly, but in some tests the exception is launched.

I'm using Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0.

---

**ProtocoloTest.java**

```java
package br.gov.mg.fazenda.protocolonegocio.testeintegracao;


import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.ScopeType;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.unitech.ufw.exception.UFWException;

import gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.controller.ProtocoloFacadeEJB3;
import gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.model.ProtocoloModel;
import gov.sefmg.sicaf.util.identificacao.IdentificacaoCPF;
import gov.sefmg.sicaf.util.identificacao.SolicitanteModel;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ProtocoloTest { 

    //Deve ser mantido com Deployents, outras configurações a injeção não funciona.
    @Deployment
    @DisplayName("Empacotando o EAR de testes")
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        File[] lFiles = Maven.configureResolver()
                // Define para utilizar os artefatos disponíveis no repositório local (após o "clean install")
                //.withClassPathResolution(false)
                // Define as configurações do Maven que devem ser utilizadas (contém o usuário, senha e repositório)
                .fromFile("C:/Ambiente/maven/apache-maven-3.5.2/conf/settings.xml")
                // Carrega o arquivo "pom.xml" para a identificação das dependências
                .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                // Importa tudo que é "provided" de forma a garantir que tudo necessário seja disponibilizado
                .importDependencies(ScopeType.PROVIDED)
                // Se baseia no próprio projeto a ser testado
                .resolve("gov.sefmg:protocolonegocio:1.0.0")
                // Garante que o próprio projeto seja incluído
                .withTransitivity()
                .asFile();

        // Gera o JAR com as classes de teste
        JavaArchive lJavaArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "testeArquillianProtocolo.jar")
                .addClasses(ProtocoloTest.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

        //Criando o ear, não é necessario de jogar tudo, apenas o que achar necessário para os testes.
        final EnterpriseArchive lEnterpriseArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "testeArquillianProtocolo.ear")
                .setApplicationXML("application.xml") // application.xml com configurações otimizadas, este arquivo esta presente em \src\test\resources
                .addAsApplicationResource(new File("src/test/resources/weblogic-application.xml"))
                .addAsLibrary(lJavaArchive)
                .addAsLibraries(lFiles);    

        //Sysout no console do ear configurado, sempre verificar se foi criado corretamente com as configurações
        System.out.println(lEnterpriseArchive.toString(true));

        return lEnterpriseArchive;
    }

    @EJB(lookup="ProtocoloFacadeEJB3")
    ProtocoloFacadeEJB3 protocoloFacadeEJB3;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Testa a alteração de um protocolo (Atualmente só ocorre para ITCD). Falhará pois é um protocolo fake.")
    public void testAlterarProtocoloInvalido() throws UFWException {

        NumeroProtocolo lNumeroProtocoloFake = new NumeroProtocolo(999900000012L);

        ProtocoloModel lProtocoloModel = new ProtocoloModel();
        lProtocoloModel.setProtocolo(lNumeroProtocoloFake);
        lProtocoloModel.setDataSolicitacao(new Date());

        SolicitanteModel lSolicitante = new SolicitanteModel();
        lSolicitante.setIdentificacao(new IdentificacaoCPF("88888888888"));
        lSolicitante.setNome("Teste Arquillian");

        lProtocoloModel.setSolicitante(lSolicitante);

        try {
            protocoloFacadeEJB3.alterar(lProtocoloModel);

            // Se não lançar exceção, então indica que a validação falhou.
            assertTrue(false);

        } catch (SicafAplicacaoException e) {
            assertTrue(e.getCodigoErro().equals(SicafConstantesDicionarioIf.PAR_REGISTRO_JA_REMOVIDO));
        }
    }

}
```

---

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>gov.sefmg</groupId>
        <artifactId>projeto-sefmg</artifactId>
        <version>5.8</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>protocolonegocio</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>protocolonegocio</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1.x</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-embedded</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opentest4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentest4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
.
.
.
</project>
```

---

**arquillian.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquillian
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/deployments</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="weblogic" default="true">
        <protocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
        <configuration>
            <property name="wlHome">C:/Ambiente/as/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1</property>
            <property name="domainDirectory">C:/Ambiente/as/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/siare_com_provider</property>
            <property name="middlewareHome">C:/Ambiente/as/Oracle/Middleware</property>

            <property name="adminUrl">t3://localhost:7001</property>
            <property name="adminUserName">weblogic</property>
            <property name="adminPassword">welcome1</property>
            <property name="target">AdminServer</property>
            <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

---

**application.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="7"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd">
    <display-name>ear</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>lib/protocolonegocio-1.0.0.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

---

**weblogic-application.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_7.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.7/weblogic-application.xsd">

    <!--weblogic-version:12.2.1 -->

    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>siare-client</wls:library-name>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>lib-sef</wls:library-name>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>siare-libs</wls:library-name>
    </wls:library-ref>

</wls:weblogic-application>
```

**Stacktrace**

The class "gov.sefmg.sicaf.seguranca.model.UsuarioSefModel" is in the "siare-client" library.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gov/sefmg/sicaf/seguranca/model/UsuarioSefModel
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:129)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1696.alterar(Unknown Source)
    at br.gov.mg.fazenda.protocolonegocio.testeintegracao.ProtocoloTest.testAlterarFluxoInvalido(ProtocoloTest.java:309)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8$1.invokeMethod(Arquillian.java:325)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.MethodInvoker$1.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:18)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ContainerTestExecuter.execute(ContainerTestExecuter.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:139)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:15)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:332)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:215)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:279)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.on(BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:273)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:166)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:115)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:61)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:139)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:117)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3786)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3752)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2451)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gov/sefmg/sicaf/seguranca/model/UsuarioSefModel
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.asRemoteException(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:60)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.handleSystemException(BaseRemoteObject.java:581)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.handleSystemException(BaseRemoteObject.java:537)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.postInvoke1(BaseRemoteObject.java:365)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessRemoteObject.postInvoke1(StatelessRemoteObject.java:20)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseRemoteObject.java:307)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invokeInternal(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:67)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:21)
    at gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.controller.ProtocoloFacadeEJB3_frcos0_ProtocoloFacadeEJB3Impl.alterar(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:86)
    ... 142 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gov/sefmg/sicaf/seguranca/model/UsuarioSefModel
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at weblogic.rmi.utils.Utilities.getRemoteMethodsAndSignatures(Utilities.java:370)
    at weblogic.rmi.utils.Utilities.getRemoteMethodsAndSignatures(Utilities.java:360)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ClientRuntimeDescriptor.isInterAppClassLoaderNeeded(ClientRuntimeDescriptor.java:313)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ClientRuntimeDescriptor.findLoader(ClientRuntimeDescriptor.java:278)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ClientRuntimeDescriptor.getClassLoader(ClientRuntimeDescriptor.java:168)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubGenerator.generateStub(StubGenerator.java:843)
    at weblogic.rmi.extensions.StubFactory.getStub(StubFactory.java:73)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo.resolveObject(StubInfo.java:410)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo.readResolve(StubInfo.java:332)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1248)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2073)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
    at weblogic.rmi.extensions.server.CBVInputStream.readObject(CBVInputStream.java:64)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.unmarshalReturn(ServerRequest.java:127)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:555)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:313)
    at gov.sefmg.sicaf.retaguarda.servico.controller.RetaguardaServicoFacade_lgeqsw_HomeImpl_12213_WLStub.create(Unknown Source)
    at gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.controller.ProtocoloRN.getRetaguardaServicoFacade(ProtocoloRN.java:264)
    at gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.controller.ProtocoloRN.validarPermissao(ProtocoloRN.java:228)
    at gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.controller.ProtocoloRN.alterar(ProtocoloRN.java:192)
    at gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.controller.ProtocoloFacadeBean.alterar(ProtocoloFacadeBean.java:104)
    at gov.sefmg.sicaf.protocolo.controller.ProtocoloFacadeEJB3_frcos0_ProtocoloFacadeEJB3Impl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invokeInternal(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:54)
    ... 149 more
```

Can anyone give a tip?

Comment: The error raised is NoClassDefFoundError and not a ClassNotFoundException. So far, it apears that le library is found by WebLogic and your application but someting is going wrong when WebLogic tries to load classes. Have a look at Weblogic server log file to get the complete stack trace and the root exception.

Comment: Thank you @EmmanuelCollin, your tip helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Weblogic merge virtually the library directory of a shared library in the library directory of the application.

My shared libraries are using "**libs**" as library directory.

However, the application is using "**lib**" as library directory.

Because of this, Weblogic doesn't merge the content.